# 4x8 bit int to 32 bit integer

Tags: c++, int, 32-bit, 8-bit

I have

```
_int8 arr[0] = 0;
_int8 arr[1] = 0;
_int8 arr[2] = 14;
_int8 arr[3] = 16;
```

I need to convert it to one _int32 using as arr[0] as first part <..> and arr[3] as last.
In the end it should be

```
_int32 back = 3600;
```

Should I use bit shifts or smth like that to achieve this?

Comment: Your code isn't valid, you cannot create an array with 0 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the byte ordering (i.e. big endian or little endian, check it out on wikipedia), and the array is set up in the right order you can just do:

```
back = *(_int32 *)arr;
```

That'll just interpret your array of 4 bytes as a buffer holding a single 32-bit integer.  In your example though, I think you've got it set up for big endian and x86 isn't.  So you'd need to swap some bytes.

For instance:

```
_int32 back = arr[0] << 24 | arr[1] << 16 | arr[2] << 8 | arr[3];
```

or something like that.

Comment: ...x86 is most definitely little-endian.

Comment: x86 is little-endian; the OP's layout would be big-endian.

Comment: i dont know about little or big endian, but that worked :D will study it later. thanks.

Comment: Isn't accessing a value through a pointer of the wrong type undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

Cast them all to `int` then use:

```
(arr[0] << 24) | (arr[1] << 16) | (arr[2] << 8) | arr[3]
```

Alternatively:

```
_int32 back = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    back = (back << 8) | arr[i];
```

Comment: You might want or need to convert to uint to avoid problems with sign bit extension.

Comment: @hardmath: True, I guess it depends what he wants.

Comment: @hardmath Actually I do not follow. Where does signedness intervene when using left shifts? If there had been right shifts in Peter's answer I would have understood, but here I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: Signedness intervenes before the shifts, when you do the conversions.  If I have a signed byte int8 and covert to int32, I expect "negative" values to be sign extended to negative values.  Perhaps gemaxas's question is open to interpretation, but the way I read it means just placing the bytes in the correct order.  Using a bitwise OR to do that (as Peter suggested) would require suppressing any sign extension.  Nick's solution (aliasing the same piece of memory) is maybe a little cleaner because it avoids the issue.

Comment: I never understand why bit shifting is even considered when unions are available.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably my SCO compiler but I think I've had problems if I didn't use (arr[0]&0xff) and so forth for doing the shifts. Certainly doesn't hurt anything.